# You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null. Adapter Class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-room

Im using Room DataBase, and im trying to paste an image in a RecyclerView. But when im trying to retrieve data to adapter class, then im get
`You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).`
In other topics i saw about isAdded() methods, but i cant use that in Adapter class

This is my clickListener from parentClass

```java
        ARB.contRem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ARB.remText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    ARB.err.setText("errCode");
                }
                else if(ARB.dateFromCalendar.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    ARB.err.setText("errCode");
                }
                else {

                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ARB.addImageRem.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Uri uri = getImageUri(getContext(), bitmap);

                    ARVM.addReminder(ARB.remText.getText().toString(),
                            ARB.dateFromCalendar.getText().toString(),
                            false,
                            uri.toString());

                    Navigation.findNavController(v).popBackStack();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is from AdapterClass

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull reminderViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(rems.get(position).getImages());



        Glide.with(ct).load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(holder.binding.imageView);

        holder.binding.textrow.setText(rems.get(position).getTextRem());
        holder.binding.daterow.setText(rems.get(position).getDateRem());
        holder.binding.isdone.setChecked(rems.get(position).isDone());

    }
```

Thats what im get after trying to retrieve data

```
2021-09-23 15:28:10.308 5391-5391/com.example.rempractice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rempractice, PID: 5391
    java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:769)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:801)
        at com.example.rempractice.project.View.adapters.reminderAdapter.onBindViewHolder(reminderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.example.rempractice.project.View.adapters.reminderAdapter.onBindViewHolder(reminderAdapter.java:19)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
2021-09-23 15:28:10.308 5391-5391/com.example.rempractice E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: in `Glide.with(ct).load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(holder.binding.imageView);`, what is ct ?

Comment: @OmarShawky Context, im just initialize ```Context ct```

Comment: you can't and shouldn't initialize a context yourself.

Comment: im added ```ct.getContextActivity()```. is it works?

Comment: check my answer and tell me if it worked.

Comment: I guess it worked, now time for a friendly advice for your programming future, you should use an uppercase letter at the start of class name, as I noticed your holder is called `reminderViewHolder` instead of `ReminderViewHolder`. and you can use a string Uri as parameter for Glide, you don't have to put it inside File object or even parse it with Uri Object, if you have just the uri string it will work as intended to avoid wasting time in initializing unnecessary objects.

Comment: appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in this cases usually pass a reference to the host fragment or its context to the adapter constructor to keep it and use it when it needs to in Glide like this :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<reminderViewHolder > {
    private final Fragment hostFragment;
    public MyAdapter (Fragment m_hostFragment) {
            this.hostFragment = m_hostFragment;
    }

    ...

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull reminderViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(rems.get(position).getImages());
            Glide.with(hostFragment).load( uri).into(holder.binding.imageView);
    }

}
```

and when I initialize my adapter in my fragment I would just pass my fragment reference

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@Nullable  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       MyAdapter pagesAdapter = new MyAdapter (this);
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

---

### Update to what we're talking about in comments

it depends on what you're returning from the getImages method. I don't know what are you returning there, but you should be returning only one string that belong to only one image at a time.

RecyclerView is a list with each row/column representing a different holder, for each holder RecyclerView calls onBindHolder to initialize it, if you want to show multiple images you should show each one in a different holder and RecyclerView will call onBindHolder multiple times until all your arraylist data's is on the screen.

so as an assumption if your data ArrayList if of type string where each item holds one image uri string, then it's enough to get the uri string in one `onBindViewHolder`.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<reminderViewHolder>{
    private final Fragment hostFragment;
    List<String> photos ; 
    public MyAdapter (Fragment m_hostFragment,List<String> photos) {
            this.hostFragment = m_hostFragment;
            this.photos = photos;
    }

    ...

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull reminderViewHolder holder, int position) {
            String photo_Uri = photos.get(position);
            Glide.with(hostFragment).load(photo_Uri).into(holder.binding.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }
}
```

and your RecyclerView will call onBindViewHolder as many times as getItemCount returns to represent all your data.

Comment: that's works! thanks a lot! but anyway my pictures doesnt displayed, logs says the path doesnt found

Comment: well maybe your uri isn't valid, try to print it and tell me what it looks like? use a `Log.e ("uri" , uri.toString())` to print it.

Comment: ```E/uri: content://media/external/images/media/45```

Comment: that seems like a valid one that might lead to an image, I really don't know the exact problem in this case, you should maybe start a new question with this issue if you couldn't solve it yourself.

Comment: maybe include the code of how do you get uri's from your external storage, what's the source of data.

Comment: before ur answer im use String for retrieve photos, not List, may be that was a problem